# How to count individual records of table with total count

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get count of individual records in a table on the basis of type.
My "types" are:

```
delhi
mumbai
banglore
calcutta
```

.

```
Delhi consist 8000 records
banglore consist 2000 records
mumbai consist of 31000 record
calcutta consist of 4000 record
```

I need this individual records with total recors count

```
Delhi consist 8000 records
banglore consist 2000 records
mumbai consist of 31000 record
calcutta consist of 4000 record
totoal records  45000
```

I use this **query** --

```
SELECT TYPE ,COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM `caselaw` GROUP BY TYPE  ORDER BY COUNT DESC;
```

and I'm getting this only

```
Delhi consist 8000 records
banglore consist 2000 records
mumbai consist of 31000 record
calcutta consist of 4000 record
```

but I also need this

```
totoal records  45000
```

**my table structure is**

```
id type data 
1  Delhi abc
2 mumbai xyz
3 mumbai mno
1  Delhi xyz
2 mumbai abc
3 mumbai bla
1  Delhi bla
2 banglore  etc
3 mumbai  etc
```

Comment: you can use OVER() only in sql server. Is this a Mysql question ?

Comment: yes this is mysql question

Answer (score 4):

i suggest a UNION query, like this :

```
SELECT
  TYPE,
  COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM `caselaw`
GROUP BY TYPE
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
UNION
SELECT
  'total records' AS TYPE,
  COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM `caselaw`;
```

Comment: Why do you use a `UNION`?. Are you expecting duplicates? If not I would recommend a `UNION ALL`?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do this

```
SELECT TYPE ,COUNT(*) TYPE_COUNT, (select count(*) from caselaw) TOTAL_RECORDS
          FROM caselaw GROUP BY TYPE  ORDER BY TYPE_COUNT DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT   TYPE, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM table_name GROUP BY TYPE 
UNION
SELECT   'total records' AS TYPE, COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM table_name ;